# Passing values into p5's canvas, instancing

Tags: javascript, class, canvas, instantiation, p5.js

Let's say I have several p5 canvases on one page, and I've chosen to use instancing to split them up. Because many of the methods will perform the same operations, I've made a superclass. It looks something like this:

```
var BasicCanvas = function(p) {
    p.setup = function() {
        p.createCanvas(100, 100);
        p.background(0);
    }

    p.draw = function() {
    }
}
```

I'll have to create a subclass and pass this into a new p5 object, like this:

```
var myP5 = new p5(BasicCanvas);
```

How should I go about creating a subclass of my super in such a way it can be passed into the p5 constructor function? My ideal code setup looks like:

```
var super = function(p) {
    p.setup = function() { creation }
}

var sub1 = function(p) {
    p.draw = function() { circles }
}

var sub2 = function(p) {
    p.draw = function() { squares }
}

var myP5 = new p5(sub1);
var myP52 = new p5(sub2);
```

But coming from Java, I'm having some difficulty getting around the differences. Can you help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var superFunction = function(p) {
    p.setup = function() {
        p.createCanvas(200, 150)
        p.noStroke()
    }
}

var sub1 = function(p) {
    superFunction(p)
    p.draw = function() {
        p.background(50)
        p.fill("blue")
        p.rect(20,20,50,50)
    }
}

var sub2 = function(p) {
    superFunction(p)
    p.draw = function() {
        p.background(100)
        p.fill("red")
        p.rect(20,20,50,50)
    }
}

var myP5 = new p5(sub1)
var myP52 = new p5(sub2)
```

*Note: `super` is a reserved keyword in Javascript*